# React Native: Assets missing from bundles development build (react-native@0.72.4)

Tags: react-native, react-native-fs

I have a react-native app that used to have a static server in one of its components, it's using react-native-fs to move files around to run on the static server but the assets folder is missing and doesn't show up when using `RNFS.readDirAssets('/')` as it should.
I don't know if it has anything to do with the version of react-native but it stopped working around the time I updated I think.

My assets folder is on the root directory of the project, I tried putting it in `android/app/src/main` as people said but it doesn't work either.

My react-native.config.js file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ['./assets/', './assets/fonts'],
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-reanimated': {
      platforms: {
        ios: null,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Any idea why it happens or what can I try?

I tried fetching assets from my running bundled app but they're missing.
I expected them to show up when running `RNFS.readDirAssets('/');`